# Cambiar el nombre predeterminado de un PDF Generado con mPDF

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Buenas quisiera saber si es posible cambiar el nombre de un PDF generado por mPDF con uno Enviado Atraves del metodo POST y guardado en una variable, actualmente lo tengo de esta forma.

```
require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
$css = file_get_contents ('./css/recibo.css');
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([]);
$mpdf->WriteHtml($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHtml($html, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
$mpdf->Output('/Users/THE SCAVERNGER/Desktop/Reporte.pdf', 'F');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Pero quiero que en vez de salir con el nombre de reporte.pdf este use uno guardado en una variable he investigado un poco pero las formas que muestran son nombres guardados en varibles pero directas.

```php
$filename = 'YourFilename.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($filename , 'F');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que ya puedes obtener el nombre que quieres, usando tu misma línea puedes hacerlo con

```
$filename = 'YourFilename.pdf';

$mpdf->Output('/Users/THE SCAVERNGER/Desktop/'.$filename, 'F');
$mpdf->Output();
```

En resumen, le concatenas el nombre que quieres a la línea que te permite escribir el PDF.

Ojo con esos espacios en los nombres de las carpetas destino, sería mejor palabras unidas en **camelCase** o **snake_case**.

Comment: Pueden usar también [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687293/changing-the-default-filename-when-using-mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687293/changing-the-default-filename-when-using-mpdf)